# How do you integrate Flex 3 with Spring 2.5

Tags: spring, flex3, blazeds

Can Spring 2.5 be used with Flex 3.x
my original question was misleading

Comment: Do you want to know if Flex can be used with Spring 2.5 or Spring 3.x? It is unclear because the title and the body of this post differs.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex should be the best starting point.

You can also search http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/ for numerous articles about Spring/Flex/BlazeDS integration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

We have projects that uses Flex 3 with Spring 2.5 and another project that uses Flex 4 and Spring 2.5.

The only reason the Flex 4 project doesnt use Spring 3.x is because there wasnt a Maven depenancy for it when we started with the project

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can integrate Flex, Spring, JPA, Hibernate etcetc. I've done it some months ago, this really helped me a lot http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/fullstack_pt1.html